# Comparar os valores de uma coluna inteira do DataGridView com uma variável

Tags: winforms, vb.net, datagridview

Gostaria de comparar o valor de uma variável do tipo string com uma coluna inteira do DataGridView.

Existe um código que consulte a coluna inteira, mais ou menos assim

```vb
textbox.Text = datagridview.columns("nome_da_coluna").value
```

ou terei que criar um laço para esta consulta?

```vb
Dim sqlCmd As String = "SELECT COLUNA1, COLUNA2  FROM nome_da_tabela "
cnn = New SqlConnection(strCon)
cmd = New SqlCommand(sqlCmd, cnn)
Dim adpt As New SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd, cnn)
Dim dts As New DataSet()

Try
    cnn.Open()

    adpt.Fill(dts, "nome_da_tabela")
    datagridview.DataSource = dts
```

Answer (score 3):

Você terá de implementar um laço, pois sua necessidade é específica. A implementação do DataGridView oferece as operações necessárias para manipulação linha-a-linha X coluna-a-coluna.

Em suma a alternativa ideal é você extender DataGridView e suprir sua necessidade oferecendo a implementação desejada como um novo método nos moldes que você sugiriu, vejamos:

```vb
seuDataDridView.columns("nome_da_coluna").value
```

Porém, acredito que armazenar o conteúdo de todas a células dessa coluna não seja uma boa prática, podendo até causar estouro de memória se houverem muitos dados.

Comment: Fábio, boa tarde.

Obrigado pela suas informações porém eu gostaria que colocasse um exemplo.

Eu sei que seuDatagridView.columns("campo da tabela").value refere-se ao valor do campo porém se você colocar no código:

textbox.text = seuDatagridView.columns("campo da tabela").value

o textbox.text não aceita o valor do campo do datagridview.

Comment: user2979215 "seuDatagridView.columns("campo da tabela").value" não possui o atributo value. Eu propus que você o implementasse. O que de fato você necessita é concatenar o valor de todas as células dessa coluna e atribuí-lo ao textbox.text?

Answer (score 0):

Uma possibilidade é no próprio **SQL** ter um campo com a concatenação de todos os valores das colunas, utilizando, por exemplo, o `FOR XML`:

```
SELECT (SELECT COLUNA1 + ';' + COLUNA2 FROM nome_da_tabela FOR XML PATH(''))
```